# Microsoft dependency injection. How can I get data to a constructor injected class several layers deep

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core

This is dotNet core 2.2 project using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.

I have 3 classes.  Class A uses Class B in the constructor.  Class B uses class C, and Class C uses the ITenant interface.

ITenant determines which database will be used.

example:

```
public A(IB b)
public B(IC c)
public C(ITenant t)
```

They are setup in the injection container as follows:

```
services.AddTransient<IA, A>();
services.AddTransient<IB, b>();
services.AddTransient<IC, c>();
services.AddTransient<ITenant , HttpTenant>()>();
```

In the web project the controller uses Class A as a constructor parameter and the container createClass A and all it's dependencies.  The implementation of ITenant (HttpTenant) pulls the tenant name from an HTTP request header and gets the database informaiotn from the config file.  Everything works perfectly.

Now I need to call this from a windows service, which does not involve as HTTP request.  I have a handler that responds to a message queue and Class A is a construction parameter.  For the windows service I have a different ITenant (WindowServiceTenant):

```
services.AddTransient<ITenant , WindowServiceTenant>()>();
```

I cannot figure out how to get the tenant code into WindowServiceTenant.

- The tenant is determined at run time based on a value read form a message queue.
- By the time my handler is instantiated the WindowServiceTenant is also instantiated.
- I don't know the tenant before the handler is instated.

I need to get a reference that instance of WindowServiceTenant and provide the tenant.  Or, this implementation WindowServiceTenant needs a reference to the handler that initiated the instantiation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two solutions:

1. Configure the `WindowServiceTenant` instance with the required value before you resolve the handler
2. Communicate the value through ambient state, for instance a value that is available for the thread (`ThreadLocal<T>`) or asynchronous operation (`AsyncLocal<T>`)

The first option requires the `WindowServiceTenant` to be registered as `Scoped` service and the creation of a `IServiceScope`, from which you resolve the `WindowServiceTenant` and the appropriate handler:

```cs
// Registration
services.AddScoped<WindowServiceTenant>();
services.AddScoped<ITenant>(c => c.GetRequiredService<WindowServiceTenant>());

// Usage
using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
{
    var services = serviceScope.ServiceProvider;

    var tenant = services.GetRequiredService<WindowServiceTenant>();

    // Set the right tenant based on a value from the queue
    tenant.SetTenantValue(...);

    // Resolve and execute handler
    var handler = services.GetRequiredService(handlerType);
}
```

The previous code listing does the following:

- It registers the `WindowServiceTenant` both by its concrete type as by its interface in such a way that both resolving `WindowServiceTenant` and `ITenant` will result in the same instance during a single service scope. This is important because otherwise state is set on that scoped instance. Having multiple instances within the same service scope will obviously not yield the right result.
- When your message is handled, you start a new `IServiceScope` using the `CreateScope` extension method on `IServiceProvider`.
- Within that scope you resolve `WindowServiceTenant`. You resolve this concrete type, as the `ITenant` abstraction will have no possibility to set the right value (as that is an implementation detail)
- You store the tenant value from the queue inside the `WindowServiceTenant` instance. As this same instance is reused for the during of the service scope, it will be injected into any resolved object graph that depends on `ITenant`.